# Why doesn't my onsubmit callback work in Linux?

Tags: linux, gwt

I have created a file upload system which allows the user to
upload .txt,.xls and .csv formats.When I executed in windows it is
running fine but now when I deployed the application in linux(Debian)
using tomcat server I am facing this issue:

The onsubmit method is called for all the file formats.
onSubmitComplete method is called only when text files are uploaded.I
want to use onSubmitComplete event as I am using progress bar and
wanted to perform necessary action on this event.

Here is my code:

```
   file = new FileUpload();
   form = new FormPanel();
   file.setName("file");
   file.setTitle("select a file");

   submit = new Button("Upload");
   submit.setTitle("upload file");

  form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
   form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);





   submit.addClickHandler(this);
   form.addSubmitHandler(this);
   form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(this);
}
```

Please tell me why the same code is working fine in windows and not in
linux.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved as it was not platform dependency it was browser dependency.I now installed google chrome and now it is running fine in linux.